# Infinite while loop. How do I fix it for n number of time?

Tags: java

the statement keeps on repeating.

```
int number;
int i = 0; 

System.out.print("Enter a number: "); 
number = input.nextInt();

while(i < number)    
    System.out.println("Welcome to Java!");
```

Comment: You need to increment `i` in the loop, otherwise `i` will always be `0`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) You will be much more likely to get an answer if your question conforms to the [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 3):

**Code**

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); // Reading from System.in
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
int number = reader.nextInt();
int i = 0;
do {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Java!");
     i++;
}
while (i < number);
```

**Output**

```
Enter a number: 
5
Welcome to Java!
Welcome to Java!
Welcome to Java!
Welcome to Java!
Welcome to Java!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(i < number) {

  System.out.println("Welcome to Java!");
  i++;
}
```

you need to increment `i` by 1 one each iteration.

```
do {
   System.out.println("Welcome to Java!");
   i++;;
}while(i < number);
```

Answer (score 1):

With a while loop, it has a condition. In your case, i < number.
The while loop will run "While" this condition is true. So, to make this condition not true, i needs to be more than "number". To make i greater than the number, you need to increment it. 
You can increment it with `i++` which will add one to i, each time its called. Usually, you increment at the end of the while loop, so after your println call.

```
while(i < number){    
System.out.println("Welcome to Java!");
i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(i < number)    
System.out.println("Welcome to Java!");
```

You are not incrementing 'i' in while loop. That's why the loop is going in infinite loop.

```
while(i < number) {   
        System.out.println("Welcome to Java!");
    i++; // increment of i
}
```

That will work fine.